# How to check which Azure function currently running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have 10 timer trigger azure functions configured under a Azure Function App. Is there any way to monitor which function is currently running?

Answer (score 1):

You could check it in **Live metrics** like this:
[image]
[image]

Live metrics is auto enabled when you enable **Application Insight**. Navigate to your Application Insight page, **Live metrics** is in the left：
[image]

Comment: Live metrics not Available message: "Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK"

Comment: BTW the results what you shared shows already executed functions, i am asking for currently running functions, this does not useful. Looks like the dashboard and App insights SDK missing this info.

Comment: Firstly, maybe you should wait a minute for the live metrics starting, and check the SDK version you use. Secondly, it shows the function starts information, which I did not sign on the picture. Here is a link about Azure Live metrics : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream

Comment: Honestly the live metrics is not so useful for my usecase. It is simple and yet very important information "What function currently running?" when it comes to "serverless" world.. i expect this status of the function, for example what if my function involves long running process or i use the azure function for a scheduling purpose.

Comment: Can we use Kudu console to find the processes that are currently running? looks like it uses w3wp.exe process for all function applications

Comment: First, a defined IIS application pool is what becomes a `w3wp.exe` process when the application starts up as an IIS worker process.  It not shows your single function. Are you sure you tried use Live Metric? @ram4sof